# ¿Por qué llamamos "chuleta" a las notas que se llevan para copiar en los exámenes?

Tags: etimología, españa, sustantivos

En el DRAE podemos comprobar en la entrada para "chuleta" que es

> [**chuleta**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9330GZD%7C934FXoO)  <sub>Del valenciano *xulleta*, dim. del cat. *xulla* 'costilla'.</sub>
>
> 1. f. Costilla con carne de animal vacuno, lanar, porcino, etc.
> 2. f. Apunte que se lleva oculto para copiar en los exámenes.

El otro día usé la segunda acepción y por primera vez en mi vida (debe ser por la *deformación* causada por este sitio) me pregunté como hemos llegado a usar para denominar al trocito de papel que usamos para hacer trampas en los exámenes la misma palabra que usamos para la pieza de carne.

Digo "pieza de papel", porque en mis tiempos era lo más común. Había quien la escribía en la mesa o incluso en la piel (del brazo, por ejemplo, aunque he sabido de gente que se la escribía en los muslos, aprovechado que un profesor no podía pedirte que te subieras la falda para comprobar si tenías apuntes escritos...). Algunos hacían estos apuntes con una aguja en un boli bic (que siempre se llevaba el comentario de "Te ha tenido que costar más hacer la chuleta que aprenderte de memoria lo que lleves ahí". El método más sofisticado que yo vi en mi tiempo era fotocopiar la página del libro, reducirla en una fotocopiadora (hasta dejarla minúscula) y luego imprimirla en una lámina transparente para pegarla en el brazo. Supongo que ahora los métodos se habrán vuelto más sofisticados.

Comment: Unas teorías: https://www.muyinteresante.es/cultura/arte-cultura/articulo/ipor-que-las-chuletas-de-copiar-se-llaman-asi http://lacuriosidadmatoalhombre.blogspot.com/2011/12/chuletas.html

Comment: Antes de leer los artículos enlazados por @ukemi me he ido al CORDE y he visto varios casos de "chuleta madrileño" de finales del siglo XIX, y me preguntaba si tendría algo que ver. Curioso que precisamente los artículos ponen ese origen como posible opción.

Comment: Parece que bastante gente dice [*xulla*](https://www.racocatala.cat/forums/fil/68568/xuleta-xulleta-xulla-opineu) en catalán con el mismo sentido (el de apunte) que *xuleta/chuleta* - puede ser que el origen es en una de [sus otras definiciones](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp?Word=xulla) (que son más amplio que *xulleta*)? Unes altres hipòtesis: http://fjhernan.blogs.uv.es/2008/09/20/xulleta/

Comment: Curiosamente nunca había escuchado el término chuleta usado en otro sentido que no fuera el de la carne. En Guatemala a esa "pieza de papel" le llamamos **chivo**, pero ahora me pregunto por qué le llamamos a un trozo de papel como a una cabra bebé.

Comment: Según el *Diccionario español escolar de familias etimológicas*, que se puede descargar gratuitamente desde [aquí](http://www.lulu.com/shop/hermenegildo-de-la-campa-mart%C3%ADnez-and-luc%C3%ADa-romero-mariscal-and-francisco-romero-l%C3%B3pez/diccionario-espa%C3%B1ol-escolar-de-familias-etimol%C3%B3gicas/ebook/product-17403660.html): Papelito con notas para uso oculto en los exámenes. < valenciano *xulleta* dim. del cat. *xulla* ‘costilla’ < cat.  _*enxulla_ por disimilación de _*enxunya_ 
< lat. _axungia_, -ae ‘grasa de cerdo’. La significación escolar proviene de la jerga estudiantil.

Comment: ¿Pero qué tendrá que ver la grasa de cerdo con copiar en un examen?

Comment: Completamente irrelevante para la pregunta, pero sólo quería agregar que en Chile esto se conoce como `torpedo`.

Comment: En Colombia se le dice "copialina".

Comment: Nota: hemos creado unq [pregunta nueva](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31420/5481) para todas estas aportaciones de "en mi país a eso se le llama XYZ". Es preferible que vayan en ese post, que tendrán mejor visibilidad, que en los comentarios a esta pregunta. Gracias  todos.

Comment: En Medellín, CO le decimos "pastel" y el acto de hacerlo es "pasteliar" (@alvalongo)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voy a dar una respuesta aunque sea tentativa. La voz *chuleta* en su sentido cárnico se conoce desde el siglo XVIII, y ya aparece en el *Autoridades* en 1729. El siguiente significado en aparecer lo hizo en el DLE de 1899:

> Pieza irregular que se añade á alguna obra de manos para rellenar un hueco.

Esta acepción se puede corresponder con las acepciones 5 y 6 de la [definición actual](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9330GZD), que hablan de conceptos parecidos. Este cambio de significado posiblemente se deba al parecido físico de la pieza mencionada con una chuleta. Antes de esta fecha también se conocía como *chuleta* a la correa en la que los barberos repasan la navaja, tal y como aparece en el *Domínguez* de 1869.

Volviendo adonde íbamos, vemos que se creado una acepción de *chuleta* que encaja con la idea de "pieza que sirve para tapar algún hueco (posiblemente fallo o defecto) de una obra manual". Esta idea se puede extrapolar a la idea de la chuleta de los exámenes como la *pieza* que sirve para rellenar los huecos en tus conocimientos, y conseguir así un resultado perfecto, similar al que se consigue usando las chuletas en construcción o carpintería. O puede que la idea que se haya transmitido haya sido la de "apoyo" (a la construcción en un caso y a la redacción de exámenes en el otro).

La acepción relativa a los exámenes aparece en el DLE en 1956, aunque acabo de ver una ficha de 1925 en el Fichero General de la RAE que atestigua dicho significado.

Como en otras ocasiones, todo esto no es más que pura elucubración, pero me pareció una teoría plausible vista la cronología de creación de acepciones de la palabra. La idea de *chuleta* como algo que te ayuda a solucionar un problema también aparece en el Moliner, que en 1966 registraba como acepción de *chuleta* "pieza que se añade a veces en la confección de algunas prendas para completar la anchura o largura necesaria en algún sitio".

---

Curiosamente, encuentro la voz *chuletas* en dos textos del siglo XVI en contextos que no dan a entender su significado culinario, y que me han dejado un poco descolocado. Los pongo a continuación:

> *Desto os preçias y esto quereis pasando siempre tiempo con todos en chuletas y motes os plaza vurlar y mofar de todos: y asi agora quereis que partiçipe yo entre vos otros desta pena sin os lo mereçer.* (c 1539)
>
> *Pasadas otras cosas, que más se pueden contar por chuletas que no por historia, Gonzalo Pizarro e su gente salieron a los términos del Quito.* (c 1553 - a 1584)

Después de estos dos textos, la voz *chuleta* no vuelve a aparecer en textos en el CORDE hasta el siglo XVIII, ya sí claramente con su significado comestible. Todo esto descuadra aún más porque en el siglo XVII se escribía *chulleta* como atestigua el *Arte de cozina, pastelería, vizcochería y conseruería* de 1611. La simplificación de *ll* a *l* parece que vino más tarde.

Comment: Le voy a dar el "Accepted answer" _preventivo_ porque a) es demasiado buena como respuesta como para no hacerlo y b) como no sé si algún día aparecerá una mejor, puedo perfectamente aceptar una conjetura bien informada y razonada como respuesta hasta que otra respuesta mejore la presente.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando la otra acepción asentada en el diccionario de la Real Academia, donde una de las definiciones expresa

> Esp. Nota o conjunto de notas que utiliza quien habla en público para recordar algunos puntos de su exposición.

pienso que acaso esta denominación fue dada por el parecido estructural con una series de puntos asentados en una lista (conjunto de elementos) de acuerdo a la arquitectura análoga de un costillar (chuleta), en la que una secuencia de huesos se disponen paralelos sobre un eje (espinazo)

Hay ahí, a mi modo de ver, en ese parecido gráfico, una probable causa de la denominación.

La chuleta, estructura de información cual lista, o serie de notas asentadas sobre un papel, es un útil "*ayuda-memoria*" para quien expone (o se siente menos inseguro con este subrepticio recordatorio durante un examen)

Comment: La tesis de Charly, de solucionador de problemas, se aplica bien para otras denominaciones, como "machete", en el que la noción de herramienta prevalece