# ¿Cómo se llama (por regiones) a las notas que se llevan escondidas para copiar en los exámenes?

Tags: vocabulario, diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos

Viendo los comentarios que los usuarios han ido aportando en [¿Por qué llamamos “chuleta” a las notas que se llevan para copiar en los exámenes?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30362/5481) he decidido crear una pregunta para listar todas las variantes a lo largo y ancho de España e Hispanoamérica.

Como se explica en la pregunta enlazada, en España se llama "chuleta" (como la pieza de carne) a esas **notas o apuntes que se llevan a los exámenes para copiar (hacer trampa)**. En inglés se conoce como *crib sheet* o *cheat sheet*.

Algunos usuarios han recalcado que ese término no es común a todos los países de habla hispana y han aportado cómo se llama a esas notas de papel en sus países.

¡Completemos la lista!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99147/discussion-on-question-by-diego-como-se-llama-por-regiones-a-las-notas-que-se).

Answer (score 8):

#### Argentina

- [machete](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NmvqLKv)

#### Bolivia

- chanchullo

#### Chile

- torpedo

#### Colombia

- [comprimido](https://dle.rae.es/?id=A3Xffet)
- copialina
- chiva
- chancuco
- pastel
- [machete](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NmvqLKv)

#### Costa Rica

- [forro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=IGnCK1u)

#### Cuba

- [chivo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8vf872X)
- [acordeón](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0ZNrnK0)

#### Ecuador

- maseo
- poya o [polla](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TadfwCR)

#### El Salvador

- [acordeón](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0ZNrnK0)

#### España

- chuleta

#### Guatemala

- [chivo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8vf872X)

#### Honduras

- [acordeón](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0ZNrnK0)
- [chepe](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8gzATLH)

#### México

- [acordeón](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0ZNrnK0)

#### Nicaragua

- chuleta

#### Paraguay

- copiatín

#### Perú

- plagio
- plaje

#### Puerto Rico

- bate
- batería

#### República Dominicana

- [chivo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8vf872X)

#### Uruguay

- trencito
- [ferrocarril](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HnmdJ5y)

#### Venezuela

- chuleta

Buena parte de las palabras se han extraído de https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apunte_escondido, donde podemos leer:

> Existen diversas denominaciones para este tipo de apunte. Estas denominaciones provienen de la jerga estudiantil. Apareció por primera vez recogido por la Real Academia Española como una acepción de «chuleta», en la decimoctava edición del Diccionario de la lengua (en 1956).

Comment: En Colombia es **COPIALINA** y nunca he escuchado estas palabra "chiva, chancuco, pastel, machete" para referirse a esas notas escondidas.

Comment: Gracias por ese aporte @alvalongo. Esas aportaciones vienen de la entrada de wikipedia, así que está muy bien que puedan ser validadas por la comunidad en lugar de considerar que wikipedia siempre tiene razón.

Comment: En Colombia **chiva** es un animal, un tipo de bus, una primicia noticiosa. **chancuco** es hacer algo amañando; **machete** es una herramienta, o hacer algo tomando un atajo.